# Gradle configure task based on subproject property

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to configure a Zip task based on one of the property inside sub-projects, but the property is not yet accessible at the time of configuring the task. For instance, I want to exclude all my projects that has `toexclude = true` from my zip file. So, the `build.gradle` of the sub-projects that I want to exclude starts with this:

```
ext.toexclude = true;
...
```

And my main `build.gradle` has this task:

```
task zipContent (type: Zip){
    def excludedProjects = allprojects.findAll{Project p -> p.toexclude == true}.collect{it.name}
    println excludedProjects
    destinationDir = "/some/path"
    baseName = "myFile.zip"
    exclude excludedProjects
    from "/some/other/path"
}
```

The problem is that `excludedProjects` is always empty. Indeed, when I am executing the task, I can see `[]`. I believe this is due to the fact that the property that I set in the subproject's `build.gradle` is not available at the moment the task is configured. As a proof, if I replace the first line of the task by this:

```
def excludedProjects = allprojects.collect{it.name}
```

The task prints out all of my project's name, and the zip contains nothing (which means the problem is in the `p.toexclude == true`).

Also, if I try this:

```
task zipContent (type: Zip){

    def excludedProjects = []
    doFirst{
        excludedProjects = allprojects.findAll{Project p -> p.toexclude == true}.collect{it.name}
        println "IN DOFIRST"
        println excludedProjects
    }

    println "IN TASK CONFIG"
    println excludedProjects
    destinationDir = "/some/path"
    baseName = "myFile.zip"
    exclude excludedProjects
    from "/some/other/path"
}
```

The task prints out `IN TASK CONFIG` followed by an empty array, then `IN DOFIRST` with the array containing only the subprojects that I set `ext.toexclude == true`.

So, is there a way to get the properties of the sub-projects at configuration time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the crucial question is: At which point of the build is all necessary information available?

Since we want to know each project in the build, where the extra property `toexclude` is set to `true` and it is possible (and by design) that the property is set via the build script, we need each build script to be evaluated.

Now, we have two options:

1. By **default**, subprojects are evaluated after the parent (root) project. To ensure the evaluation of each project, we need to wait for the point of the build, where all projects are evaluated. Gradle provides a listener for that point:

   ```
   gradle.addListener(new BuildAdapter() {
       @Override
       void projectsEvaluated(Gradle gradle) {
           tasks.getByPath('zipContent').with {
               exclude allprojects.findAll { it.toexclude }.collect{ it.name }
           }
       }
   })
   ```
2. Gradle provides the method `evaluationDependsOnChildren()`, to turn the evaluation order around. It may be possible to use your original approach by calling this method before querying the excluded projects. Since this method only applies on child projects, you may try to call `evaluationDependsOn(String)` for each project in the build to also apply for 'sibling' projects. Since this solution breaks Gradle default behavior, it may have undesired side effects.

Comment: I managed to get the correct list of excluded projects from your first approach. Now, from the `projectsEvaluated` method, is there a way to call the zip task with the list of excluded projects? Ideally, I would call the zip task when another task is called.

Comment: You don't directly *call* tasks in Gradle, you create tasks and define dependencies between them. You just need to configure the task, basically in them same way as you did before. You can either register the listener from the task context, so that you can configure your task right from the listener method (basically you move my code example into your task configuration closure). Another option is to register the listener globally and search the task via [`tasks.getByPath(String)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html#getByPath-java.lang.String-).

Comment: I edited the code example to show how you can configure the task from the listener method.

Answer (score 1):

Just define `excludedProjects` outside the task

```
def excludedProjects = allprojects.findAll{Project p -> p.toexclude == true}.collect{it.name}

task zipContent (type: Zip){
    destinationDir = file("/some/path")
    baseName = "myFile.zip"
    exclude excludedProjects
    from "/some/other/path"
}
```

Comment: I tried that and the array is still empty apparently. I printed the array's content right after setting it and also inside the task, and both time it is empty. However, if I write that first line within the doFirst block inside the task and print its output, I get the desired content.

Comment: Weird because my solution should work (i tested it). Maybe you can share more of your `build.gradle` ?

Comment: There should be absolutely **no difference** between putting the definition of `excludedProjects` inside or outside the task, because the configuration closure of the task is executed directly when the task is created.

Comment: Put the def inside an "afterEvaluate" block.  The following page has an example of something that loops through all projects after the evaluation page, processing those that have tests.  You could use something similar to collect the projects that have your property..  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html  Look down the page for "Example: Adding of test task to each project which has certain property set"

Answer (score 1):

You can call [evaluationDependsOnChildren()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#evaluationDependsOnChildren--) in the root project so that child projects are evaluated before the root

Eg

```
evaluationDependsOnChildren() 
task zipContent (type: Zip) { ... }
```

Another option is to use an [afterEvaluate { ... }](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#afterEvaluate-groovy.lang.Closure-) closure to delay evaluation

Eg:

```
afterEvaluate {
    task zipContent (type: Zip) { ... } 
}
```

Comment: But the `afterEvaluate` closure will be called when the current project is evaluated, not after possible child or sibling projects are. Since he is using `allprojects`, some of them might not have been evaluated.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure at what stage `afterEvaluate{...}` is called. Its possible that this event is fired after subprojects are evaluated, easy to try and see! Otherwise my first suggestion will work

Comment: Gradle provides a special listener function [`projectsEvaluated`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/BuildListener.html) for the point of the build when all projects are evaluated. The `afterEvaluate` closure and its [listener counterpart](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/ProjectEvaluationListener.html) are project-specific.

Comment: I agree with everything you've said. But that still leaves the possibility that all projects do normal evaluation first. Then the `afterEvaluate{...} ` for each is fired. As I said I'm not sure of the timing but it's entirely possible, and worth testing